# Form Array push as second last item in array

Tags: angular

I have the following code to push a new item to the very end of the form array:

```
(<FormArray>this.invoicesForm.get('invoices')).push(this.fBuilder.group({
            id: null,
            issueDate: [null, Validators.required], // Only fill in and set the required validator for issue date if a custom date has already been chosen
            invoiceIssuedStateCode: [0],
            canEditIssueDate: [true],
            chooseDate: [false],
            issued: [false],
            paidStatus: [0],
            reference: [null],
            creditNotes: this.buildCreditNotes([]),
            lineItems: this.buildNewLineItems(this.lineItemsRecord.lineItems)
        }));
```

However I need to push this item as the second last item in the array.
How would I go about this?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of pushing, you could splice it:

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

it would work this way:

```
(<FormArray>this.invoicesForm.get('invoices')).controls
    // splicing instead of pushing
    .splice(-2, 0, this.fBuilder.group({
            // your fb config
        }));
```

notice the -2 (index -2 equals length - 2), and the 0. The -2 says where to insert or delete, the 0 that you are deleting 0 iterables, and the object  you pass is then inserted (the fb.group()).

**In short**: you are targeting index -2 (previous to last item), you are telling it to delete 0 items, and then you are pushing at that index a new item (your formGroup object). That's how splice works!

Comment: Thanks but I get a strange error saying "Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'FormArray'"

Comment: OHHHHH I get what's happening. don't splice to FormArray... splice to FormArray.controls

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript function 'splice' over the array.

```
 var index =  (<FormArray>this.invoicesForm.get('invoices')).length-1;

  fruits.splice(index, 0, this.fBuilder.group({
            id: null,
            issueDate: [null, Validators.required], // Only fill in and set the required validator for issue date if a custom date has already been chosen
            invoiceIssuedStateCode: [0],
            canEditIssueDate: [true],
            chooseDate: [false],
            issued: [false],
            paidStatus: [0],
            reference: [null],
            creditNotes: this.buildCreditNotes([]),
            lineItems: this.buildNewLineItems(this.lineItemsRecord.lineItems)
        }));
```

It will add the item as second last item in the array.

Comment: Thanks but I get a strange error saying "Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'FormArray'"

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward Can you please try fruits.insert(index,this.fBuilder.group({..........) instead of splice. You have to just provide the index and new item to the insert function.